# How to Sum Up Records in Multiple Columns in MS Access Table

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a table of Accruals by Month, with each Accrual in a separate row and the months across the top like the below.

There are also some non-numerical columns in the table such as Reference and Company as per the below.

```
              Jan-16   Feb-16  Mar-16 Reference Company   Total 
Accrual 1      $100    $200    $300       x        Z      $600  
Accrual 2      $150    $450    $550       y        A      $1,150 
Accrual 3
```

[Screenshot of Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsic7.jpg)

I want to put a Total Column at the end of the table that sums up all the monthly entries for each Accrual.

Bearing in mind that the number of monthly columns will increase by 1 each month and I don't want to have to manually change the formula to add the new month in each month.

Would be grateful for ideas on how to do this please?

Thanks

Comment: Frankly this is bad idea to hardcode month/year in column names, I would recommend to redesign database first: put accruals data in separate table with columns AccrualID, Year, Month, Value. Otherwise you will have much more other similar problems.

Comment: Listen to @SergeyS.. Access is not a spreadsheet.

Comment: I understand your comments but I need to display the data in this way. Access does offer the user the option to sum up fields using [field 1] + [field 2] + [field 3] etc so the functionality is there. But I suppose what I am trying to do is sum up a range of fields instead of having to state exactly what does fields are (given that the range of fields would vary). So I would have thought it is possible to use a variable or something to do this? Thanks

Comment: For tabular **display** you use a crosstab query. But don't store your data this way. And: [Calculated fields belong in queries, not tables.](http://allenbrowne.com/casu-14.html)

Comment: "I understand your comments but I need to display the data in this way." --  Summary data is displayed in reports and forms.  Access is a good tool for this.